# emeditorを使用する際に、行の文字色を変更する

Tags: emeditor

emeditorを使用する際に、行に「*」が含まれていたらその行の色を変えることは可能でしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

設定のプロパティの [強調(1)] ページで、[ユーザー定義の文字列と既定のキーワードの両方] を選択し、[追加] ボタンをクリックして [ユーザー定義の文字列] 一覧に、`.*\*`と入力します。そして、[行の右前部を強調]、[大文字小文字を区別]、[正規表現] チェック ボックスをチェックし、好きな色を選択します。

[image: 設定のプロパティの強調(1)]

Comment: ズバリです。どうもありがとうございました。一点追加で申し訳ないですが、「強調文字列」に選択したい文字列が無かった場合、自作は可能でしょうか？

Comment: 追加のご質問の意味がはっきりしないのですが、今回と異なる質問のようなので、右上の「質問する」をクリックして、新しい質問としていただけると幸いです。